# Why aren't both Double variables updated with same value?

Tags: java, android, double

I am trying to make an app that converts dollars to Euros. This code works but I am unsure of one thing. When i do the conversion, i don't get why the value of dollars doesn't also change. What I mean is that when i assign euros to dolars, i make them both point to the same Double object, so shouldn't the double field inside both Double objects change? If so why?

```
EditText editText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
//Extract string from there
String message = editText.getText().toString();
//Convert amount to dollars
Double dolars = Double.parseDouble(message);
Log.i("Dolars before", dolars.toString());
Double euros = dolars * 0.835791;
Log.i("Euros",euros.toString());
Log.i("Dolars after",dolars.toString());e`
```

Comment: Can you clarify? You said "when i assign euros to dolars" but where does this happen?

Comment: yes you are just printing dolars again without assigning euros to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest possible answer is that `Double` instances are *immutable*, which means that their contents can't change.

Also, let's look at the assignment line:

```
Double euros = dolars * 0.835791;
```

This line is taking advantage of a Java feature called auto-boxing and auto-unboxing. If you wanted to be explicit, you'd write it like this:

```
Double euros = Double.valueOf(dolars.doubleValue() * 0.835791);
```

Written out long-form like this, you can see that you're extracting the primitive `double` from `dolars`, performing multiplication, and then wrapping the result and assigning it to `euros`. So there's no "sharing" of values/references here.

Comment: Thanks man that was very helpful. By wrapping do you mean that the double value that is returned is then placed in the double field of Double euros?